# Looking for a pre-trained word vector with an embedding dimension of 500d (similar to glove.6B.300d)

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, word-embedding

I'm looking for a pre-trained word vector with an embedding dimension of 500 (something similar to glove.6B.300d), but I haven't been able to find one. Could anyone point me in the right direction or offer any advice on how to obtain what I'm looking for? Thanks so much!